# Transpose data in R where dynamic columns header

Tags: r, dynamic

I have data as per following  ( header are dynamic and possible to change )

```
    A   B   C   D
X   1   2   3   4
Y   5   6   7   8
Z   9   10  11  12
```

and in R I would like to transpose this data as below

```
X   A   1
X   B   2
X   C   3
X   D   4
Y   A   5
Y   B   6
Y   C   7
Y   D   8
Z   A   9
Z   B   10
Z   C   11
Z   D   12
```

I have tried to use  `melt` function in R but not succeed

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(t(df1))[c(2, 1, 3)]
#    Var2 Var1 value
#1     X    A     1
#2     X    B     2
#3     X    C     3
#4     X    D     4
#5     Y    A     5
#6     Y    B     6
#7     Y    C     7
#8     Y    D     8
#9     Z    A     9
#10    Z    B    10
#11    Z    C    11
#12    Z    D    12
```